# Does IE 6 Mobile Support AJAX?

Tags: ajax, windows-ce

I am developing a web application and that will be mainly used in Windows CE hand sets which has Windows CE 4.2 with IE 6 and I just wanted to know whether AJAX and JQuery can be used in my web app or not.

I tried using UpdatePanel in my project, but, it seems to be not working. Any advice will greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938878.aspx#ProvidingClientSideCode XMLHttpRequest is supported in Internet Explorer Mobile 6. Not sure about jQuery though.

Comment: Regarding jQuery support, this answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386810/web-browser-support-windows-embedded-vs-windows-ce-vs-windows-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have support for AJAX you need support for Javascript and for XMLHttpRequest object.
A WinCE image can include support for both:

- JScript;
- XMLHttp (xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");)

If you have IE6 mobile installed on your wince image I can imagine that both componente are included in the wince image itself.

As a consequence also JQuery is supported but if you use IE6 you have to use at max the 1.9 version: [see here](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2614553/javascript/jquery-2-0-drops-support-for-old-versions-of-internet-explorer.html)